Apache 2.4.62 not applying HeaderName and FooterName to Index
after upgrading to Apache 2.4.62? My headerName and readmeName are no longer inserting into the index. All other customizations work fine. I have also tried inserting:
  HeaderName header.html
  ReadmeName  footer.html

in several domains .htaccess and still no luck. Autoindex is definitely working.
I have checked that the files still exist and can be read. Any ideas?

I have verified that these mods are installed: authz_core, authz_host, autoindex ,alias
